# WindowBackground: Image with selected color

Tags: android, background, android-layout

I want to have as the background of my application an image, with a color the user can choose. The picture has got a transparent background and so I would like to put it over a colorous screen.
Is that possible?

Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes it is possible. For example create a spinner with different coloritems.You
set the Color with :

```
v.setBackgroundColor(YOURSELECTEDCOLOR );
```

with a listener like this you can set your color:

```
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id) {

  Spinner temp = (Spinner) parent;
  switch(temp.getId()){
       case 1:
       YOOURSELECTEDCOLOR="GREEN";
       break;
       case 2:
       YOOURSELECTEDCOLOR="BLUE";
       break;
       ...  
}
```